# Elementor sets my input button's color and background color the same

Tags: wordpress, elementor

This class .elementor-kit-8 input[type="submit"] sets the button's color and background color the same essentially making the text look invisible any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a typical Elementor glitch.. My usual workaround is simply adding custom CSS by (potentially adding a class or ID) and then selecting the class/ID and adding the respective hex code.

If you want the text color to be white, for instance, your code would look something like this:

```css
 .password-submit {
    color: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: Kinda annoying that elementor does that.